# What is the field $\vec{M}$. Is it induced by the magnetic field $\vec{B}$

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I'm trying to understand what exactly is the field $\vec{M}$, is it induced by the magnetic field $\vec{B}$, if so does $\vec{M}$ affects $\vec{B}$ inside a material and so on.

Since $\vec{M}$ is about magnetization, I guess it is only present in a material and not in the vacuum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbf{M}$ is the magnetization vector, and is often defined as the "magnetic dipole moment per unit volume." Mathematically, it is a quantity such that

$$\mathbf{m}=\iiint\mathbf{M}dV$$

where $\mathbf{m}$ is the system's total magnetic dipole moment. Griffiths defines $\mathbf{M}$ by its relation to the vector potential as
$$\mathbf{A(r)}=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int\frac{\mathbf{M(r')}\times\mathbf{(r-r')}}{\mathbf{|r-r'|}^3}dV'$$

Note that these equations are true no matter where $\mathbf{M}$ comes from.

Now, as it turns out, $\mathbf{M}$ can come from a few different places. Things like permanent magnets have non-zero magnetization. And yes, magnetization can also be induced by an external magnetic field. In these cases, the relationship between magnetization and the external field (technically, the H-field) are related by the magnetic susceptibility.

At least in classical electrodynamics, a vacuum cannot be magnetized. Not sure about QED, though.